# Find the most used word in the text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm calculating how many different words there are. How can I find the most used word in the text. How can I add this to the code.

```
int kacFarkliKelime(String metin) {
    String yeniMetin = metin.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^\w\s]+'), "");
    List<String> liste = yeniMetin.split(
      " ",
    );
    List farklilar = [];
    
    liste.forEach((element) {
      String sorgulanan = element.toLowerCase();
      if (!farklilar.contains(sorgulanan)) {
        farklilar.add(sorgulanan);
      }
    });
    if(farklilar[0])
    return farklilar.length;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd build a `Map<String, int>` that'd count each word as it is seen, then get a list of keys sorted by descending value order. (There's a few handy "sort by" functions in package:collection to help with that.)  The code for that would look like:

```
var words = (use a regex to extract words);
var count = <String,int>{};
for (final w in words) {
  count[w] = 1 + (count[w] ?? 0);
}
var ordered = count.keys.toList();
ordered.sort((a, b) => count[b].compareTo(count[a]));
```

Now the first element of ordered is the word with the most appearances in the text.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I got this error.The method 'sort' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'sort'.

Comment: Sorry... hadn't tested the code.  Fixed now.